# Mockito when thenreturn returns null

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to stub few classes but Mockito returns null always

```
class test {
  A mockA = mock(A.class);
  B mockB = mock(B.class);

  when(mockA.getB()).thenReturn(mockB);
  boolean b = mockA.getB() == null //true
}

interface A {
 B getB();
}

interface B {}
```

What could be the reason of that?

Comment: what is mockA.class? mb it should be A.class

Comment: yeap it was a mistake, sorry.

Comment: editing away the original problem and posting invalid code as your example are not helpful. voting to close as a typographical error.

Comment: I made a mistake in other place in my code, but I thought that the reason is in this part of code, so problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
class test {
    A mockA = mock(A.class);
    B mockB = mock(B.class);

    when(mockA.getB()).thenReturn(mockB);
    boolean b = mockA.getB() == null; // Should be false
}

interface A {
    B getB();
}

interface B {}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake. My code is exactly like yours now.

Comment: And still returns `null`?

Comment: When I run it `mockA.getB()` returns the `mockB` object. Maybe edit your question and copy and paste your actual code.

Comment: You are right, it was a mistake in my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
class test {
A mockA = mock(A.class);
B mockB = mock(B.class);
when(mockA.getB()).thenReturn(mockB);
boolean b = mockA.getB() == null;
}
```

Mockito will create mocked object for interface B (B mockB = mock(B.class);) and you have mocked mockA.getB() to return mocked object (when(mockA.getB()).thenReturn(mockB);) so surely  boolean b = mockA.getB() == null; will be false

Here is code it may help you

Here is code if it may help you    import org.mockito.Mockito;

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String dd[]) {
    A mockA = Mockito.mock(A.class);
    B mockB = Mockito.mock(B.class);

    Mockito.when(mockA.getB()).thenReturn(mockB);
    boolean b = mockA.getB() == null; // true
    System.out.println(b);
}
}

interface A {
B getB();
}
interface B {
}
```